# isEqualToString does not work as supposed to?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

Ok, I've done this before, its easy, but for some reason I do not understand why the following two strings do not equal each other! Any ideas? I am certain it will be something very easy that I am not seeing:

```
NSString *texture1name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"world%dΙnGameScrollBackground1", 0];

NSLog(@"IS EQUAL: %d", [@"world0InGameScrollBackground1" isEqualToString:texture1name]);
NSLog(@"This: %@ equal to: %@", texture1name, @"world0InGameScrollBackground1");
```

When I run the above code I get a:

```
IS EQUAL: 0
This: world0ΙnGameScrollBackground1 equal to: world0InGameScrollBackground1
```

Its exactly the same string, no spaces or anything!
Please help,
Thanks!

Comment: Change your 2nd log to `NSLog(@"This: '%@' equal to: %@", texture1name, @"world0InGameScrollBackground1");` See if there is any space or newline showing between the quotes.

Comment: If I do Cmd+F (research in the page here), we see that the "I" in "InGames" seems different... Search "world0", then "workd0I", you'll see.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Somehow you've got the Greek letter [iota](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iota) in your format string `@"world%dΙnGameScrollBackground1"` in place of an uppercase "i", causing the strings to mismatch. Just re-type the format string using the "I" character and you should be good to go. Or just copy-paste this:

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"world%dInGameScrollBackground1", 0];`